# Margin bottom not working on %100 div

Tags: html, scrollbar, margin

I have the following html code:

```
<html>
 <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
   <div id="outer" style="height:100%;">
     <div id="header" style="height:40px; background:blue;">Header</div>
     <div id="main" style="height:100%; margin-bottom:-40px; background:red; overflow:auto;">
        <p style="height:1000px">Main</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I only want the vertical scroll to appear on the main div when the content within it exceeds the viewable area, it seems the margin-bottom on the main div is not working.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What does the vertical scroll bar have to do with `margin-bottom`?

Comment: Your code produces no scrollbar, even with a ridiculous amount of content: http://jsfiddle.net/r7JgK/2/

Comment: I have posted new code, please check it. I want this page to operate like a web app where the main div is always at 100% of the viewable page, but as the header is 40px high I always get double vertical scrollbars when the content within the main div exceeds the viewable area.

Comment: Please refer to this url http://jsbin.com/uvigo5/2 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be solving the wrong problem, actually. If you just want to get rid of the scroll bar for the body itself, set body's style to `overflow:hidden`.

```
<html>
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;overflow:hidden;">
   <div id="outer" style="height:100%;">
     <div id="header" style="height:40px; background:blue;">Header</div>
     <div id="main" style="height:100%; margin-bottom:-40px; background:red; overflow:auto;">
        <p style="height:1000px">Main</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This should resolve the margin issue, and then all you have to do is keep the sizes right.

Comment: Note that if you don't set the bottom margin correctly, the inside scrollbar's bottom will travel below the bottom of the page and you won't be able to reach it, so make sure to account for all the paddings, margins, and borders as you add to the CSS. I would avoid adding any of the above to `main`, and instead add such declarations to the contents of `main` where needed.

Comment: Thanks for you help but this doesn't solve my issue, I need the inside scrollbar to sit correctly, the header height is still pushing down the main div beyond the bottom of the page. (http://jsbin.com/epuxi4/). Is there not away to avoid this?

Comment: Oh, I see. The positioning of the main element can be done absolutely to achieve that. See http://jsbin.com/epuxi4/5